# FileUploader error when uploading images

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

I'm using nopcommerce and I've added code for photo upload using file uploader but I'm getting this error:

> Reason: XHR returned response code 404

```
@model ProductDetailsModel
@using Nop.Core.Domain.Seo;
@using Nop.Core.Infrastructure;
@using Nop.Web.Models.Catalog;
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ColumnsOne.cshtml";

    //title
    Html.AddTitleParts(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.MetaTitle) ? Model.MetaTitle : Model.Name);
    //meta
    Html.AddMetaDescriptionParts(Model.MetaDescription);
    Html.AddMetaKeywordParts(Model.MetaKeywords);
    //page class
    Html.AppendPageCssClassParts("html-product-details-page");

    var seoSettings = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<SeoSettings>();

    //canonical URL
    if (seoSettings.CanonicalUrlsEnabled)
    {
        var productUrl = Url.RouteUrl("Product", new { SeName = Model.SeName }, this.Request.Url.Scheme);
        Html.AddCanonicalUrlParts(productUrl);
    }

    //open graph META tags
    if (seoSettings.OpenGraphMetaTags)
    {
        Html.AddHeadCustomParts("<meta property=\"og:type\" content=\"product\" />");
        Html.AddHeadCustomParts("<meta property=\"og:title\" content=\"" + Html.Encode(Model.Name) + "\" />");
        Html.AddHeadCustomParts("<meta property=\"og:description\" content=\"" + Html.Encode(Nop.Core.Html.HtmlHelper.StripTags(Model.MetaDescription)) + "\" />");
        Html.AddHeadCustomParts("<meta property=\"og:image\" content=\"" + Model.DefaultPictureModel.ImageUrl + "\" />");
        Html.AddHeadCustomParts("<meta property=\"og:url\" content=\"" + Request.Url.AbsoluteUri + "\" />");
        Html.AddHeadCustomParts("<meta property=\"og:site_name\" content=\"" + Html.Encode(Model.CurrentStoreName) + "\" />");
    }

    //Twitter META tags
    if (seoSettings.TwitterMetaTags)
    {
        Html.AddHeadCustomParts("<meta property=\"twitter:card\" content=\"summary\" />");
        Html.AddHeadCustomParts("<meta property=\"twitter:site\" content=\"" + Html.Encode(Model.CurrentStoreName) + "\" />");
        Html.AddHeadCustomParts("<meta property=\"twitter:title\" content=\"" + Html.Encode(Model.Name) + "\" />");
        Html.AddHeadCustomParts("<meta property=\"twitter:description\" content=\"" + Html.Encode(Nop.Core.Html.HtmlHelper.StripTags(Model.MetaDescription)) + "\" />");
        Html.AddHeadCustomParts("<meta property=\"twitter:image\" content=\"" + Model.DefaultPictureModel.ImageUrl + "\" />");
        Html.AddHeadCustomParts("<meta property=\"twitter:url\" content=\"" + Request.Url.AbsoluteUri + "\" />");
    }


    Html.AddCssFileParts("~/Scripts/fineuploader/fineuploader-4.2.2.min.css");
    Html.AddScriptParts("~/Scripts/fineuploader/jquery.fineuploader-4.2.2.min.js");


    <script type="text/template" id="qq-template-gallery">

        <div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader qq-gallery" qq-drop-area-text="Drop files here">
            <div class="qq-total-progress-bar-container-selector qq-total-progress-bar-container">
                <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-total-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar qq-total-progress-bar"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="qq-upload-drop-area-selector qq-upload-drop-area" qq-hide-dropzone>
                <span class="qq-upload-drop-area-text-selector"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button">
                <div>Upload a file</div>
            </div>
            <span class="qq-drop-processing-selector qq-drop-processing">
                <span>Processing dropped files...</span>
                <span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner-selector qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span>
            </span>
            <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list" role="region" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions removals">
                <li>
                    <span role="status" class="qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text"></span>
                    <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector qq-progress-bar-container">
                        <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner"></span>
                    <div class="qq-thumbnail-wrapper">
                        <img class="qq-thumbnail-selector" qq-max-size="120" qq-server-scale>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="qq-upload-cancel-selector qq-upload-cancel">X</button>
                    <button type="button" class="qq-upload-retry-selector qq-upload-retry">
                        <span class="qq-btn qq-retry-icon" aria-label="Retry"></span>
                        Retry
                    </button>

                    <div class="qq-file-info">
                        <div class="qq-file-name">
                            <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
                            <span class="qq-edit-filename-icon-selector qq-edit-filename-icon" aria-label="Edit filename"></span>
                        </div>
                        <input class="qq-edit-filename-selector qq-edit-filename" tabindex="0" type="text">
                        <span class="qq-upload-size-selector qq-upload-size"></span>
                        <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-delete">
                            <span class="qq-btn qq-delete-icon" aria-label="Delete"></span>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-pause-selector qq-upload-pause">
                            <span class="qq-btn qq-pause-icon" aria-label="Pause"></span>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-continue-selector qq-upload-continue">
                            <span class="qq-btn qq-continue-icon" aria-label="Continue"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <dialog class="qq-alert-dialog-selector">
                <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
                <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                    <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Close</button>
                </div>
            </dialog>

            <dialog class="qq-confirm-dialog-selector">
                <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
                <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                    <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">No</button>
                    <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Yes</button>
                </div>
            </dialog>

            <dialog class="qq-prompt-dialog-selector">
                <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
                <input type="text">
                <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                    <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Ok</button>
                </div>
            </dialog>
        </div>
    </script>
}
<!--product breadcrumb-->
@section Breadcrumb
{
    @Html.Partial("_ProductBreadcrumb", Model.Breadcrumb)
}
@Html.Widget("productdetails_after_breadcrumb", Model.Id)
<div class="page product-details-page">
    <div class="page-body">
        @Html.Widget("productdetails_top", Model.Id)
        @using (Html.BeginRouteForm("Product", new { SeName = Model.SeName }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "product-details-form" }))
        {
            <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" data-productid="@Model.Id">
                <div class="product-essential">
                    @Html.Widget("productdetails_before_pictures", Model.Id)
                    <!--product pictures-->
                    @Html.Partial("_ProductDetailsPictures", Model)
                    @Html.Widget("productdetails_after_pictures", Model.Id)
                    <div class="overview">
                        @Html.Partial("_Discontinued", Model)
                        <div class="product-name">
                            <h1 itemprop="name">
                                @Model.Name
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                        @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ShortDescription))
                        {
                            <div class="short-description">
                                @Html.Raw(Model.ShortDescription)
                            </div>
                        }
                        @Html.Widget("productdetails_overview_top", Model.Id)
                        <!--product reviews-->
                        @Html.Partial("_ProductReviewOverview", Model.ProductReviewOverview)
                        <!--manufacturers-->
                        @Html.Partial("_ProductManufacturers", Model.ProductManufacturers)
                        <!--availability-->
                        @Html.Partial("_Availability", Model)
                        <!--SKU, MAN, GTIN, vendor-->
                        @Html.Partial("_SKU_Man_GTIN_Ven", Model)
                        <!--delivery-->
                        @Html.Partial("_DeliveryInfo", Model)
                        <!--sample download-->
                        @Html.Partial("_DownloadSample", Model)
                        <!--attributes-->
                        @{
                            var dataDictAttributes = new ViewDataDictionary();
                            dataDictAttributes.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = string.Format("attributes_{0}", Model.Id);
                            @Html.Partial("_ProductAttributes", Model.ProductAttributes, dataDictAttributes)
                        }
                        <!--gift card-->
                        @{
                            var dataDictGiftCard = new ViewDataDictionary();
                            dataDictGiftCard.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = string.Format("giftcard_{0}", Model.Id);
                            @Html.Partial("_GiftCardInfo", Model.GiftCard, dataDictGiftCard)
                        }
                        <!--rental info-->
                        @{
                            var dataDictRental = new ViewDataDictionary();
                            dataDictRental.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = string.Format("rental_{0}", Model.Id);
                            @Html.Partial("_RentalInfo", Model, dataDictRental)
                        }
                        <!--price & add to cart-->
                        @{
                            var dataDictPrice = new ViewDataDictionary();
                            dataDictPrice.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = string.Format("price_{0}", Model.Id);
                            @Html.Partial("_ProductPrice", Model.ProductPrice, dataDictPrice)

                            @Html.Partial("_ProductTierPrices", Model.TierPrices)

                            var dataDictAddToCart = new ViewDataDictionary();
                            dataDictAddToCart.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = string.Format("addtocart_{0}", Model.Id);
                            @Html.Partial("_AddToCart", Model.AddToCart, dataDictAddToCart)
                        }
                        <!--wishlist, compare, email a friend-->
                        <div class="overview-buttons">
                            @Html.Widget("productdetails_inside_overview_buttons_before", Model.Id)
                            @{
                                var dataDictAddToWishlist = new ViewDataDictionary();
                                dataDictAddToWishlist.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = string.Format("addtocart_{0}", Model.Id);
                                @Html.Partial("_AddToWishlist", Model.AddToCart, dataDictAddToWishlist)
                            }
                            @Html.Partial("_CompareProductsButton", Model)
                            @Html.Partial("_ProductEmailAFriendButton", Model)
                            @Html.Widget("productdetails_inside_overview_buttons_after", Model.Id)
                        </div>
                        @Html.Partial("_ShareButton", Model)
                        @Html.Widget("productdetails_overview_bottom", Model.Id)
                    </div>
                    @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.FullDescription))
                    {
                        <div class="full-description" itemprop="description">
                            @Html.Raw(Model.FullDescription)
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
                @Html.Widget("productdetails_before_collateral", Model.Id)
                <div class="product-collateral">
                    @Html.Partial("_ProductSpecifications", Model.ProductSpecifications)
                    @Html.Partial("_ProductTags", Model.ProductTags)
                </div>
                @Html.Action("ProductsAlsoPurchased", "Product", new { productId = Model.Id })
                @Html.Action("RelatedProducts", "Product", new { productId = Model.Id })
            </div>
        }
        @Html.Widget("productdetails_bottom", Model.Id)

        @Html.Partial("Picture")
        <div id="fine-uploader-gallery"></div>
        <script>
        var galleryUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
            element: document.getElementById("fine-uploader-gallery"),
            template: 'qq-template-gallery',
            request: {
                endpoint: '/server/uploads'
            },
            thumbnails: {
                placeholders: {
                    waitingPath: '/source/placeholders/waiting-generic.png',
                    notAvailablePath: '/source/placeholders/not_available-generic.png'
                }
            },
            validation: {
                allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png']
            },
            callbacks: {
                onError: function (id, name, errorReason, xhrOrXdr) {
                    alert(qq.format("Error on file number {} - {}.  Reason: {}", id, name, errorReason));
                }
            },
            cors: {
                //all requests are expected to be cross-domain requests
                expected: false,

                //if you want cookies to be sent along with the request
                sendCredentials: false
            },
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            }
        });
        </script>
    </div>


</div>
```

Comment: If you can format the question properly it would be much easier to see what's going on

Answer (score 3):

There is a known issue with nopCommerce regarding this. If your app is running under IIS Virtual Directory, Tiny MCE is likely not able to find your image.

Edit the following file:

\Administration\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\RichEditor.cshtml

Uncomment the lines:

```
//allowJbimages = true;
//allowRoxyFileman = false;
```

To:

```
allowJbimages = true;
allowRoxyFileman = false;
```

References:
[1] https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/issues/142
[2] https://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/35370/virtual-directory-not-included-in-the-images-urls.aspx